# No records shown after uploading a dataset as csv file to hive

Tags: hadoop

I have a table on hadoop created using the code as below:

```
create table XXXX 
(...some data definitions...)
row format delimited
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = '^')
(...some other properties...)
```

and then I moved to the `HDFS`, found the respective table under the database and upload a `csv` file onto it. My `csv` file's columns follow the order as defined by the create table statement with the partition column put at the end. After I successfully uploaded the `csv` file, it turns out that when
I do `'select * from mydataset'` the query produced no results. 
When I clicked into the `csv` file, it doesn't seem wrong, the delimiter '^' and the data fields are still there.

1. I want to know where the problem lies, would the result differ if I
   use  { row format delimited fields terminated by '^' } instead?
2. Is what I have done to upload the `csv` file the same as using a load
   data inpath statement? Can I use load data inpath statement instead
   and would it be faster than manually uploading the csv file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are Two ways to Upload the data into Hive table
1) Load Command
2) Follow the below steps.
    Step 1: Create folder on HDFS (Example: hadoop fs -mkidr /user/Username/orders)
    Step 2: Upload the Files to the above folder(Example: hadoop fs -put csvfiles /user/Username/orders/)
    Step 3: Create the External Hive table using the above folder. After this operation you can query and test the data
            Example:
              Create External Table ordersfeed(
                order_id BIGINT,
                order_name String
              )
              ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
              LOCATION '/user/Username/orders'
              STORED AS TEXTFILE;
    Step 4: Create Internal Hive table
          Create  Table ordersdata(
            order_id BIGINT,
            order_name String
          )
          STORED AS ORC
    Step 5: Insert the Data from External table to internal table
          Example:
            INSERT INTO TABLE ordersdata
            SELECT * FROM ordersfeed;
Note:
  1) Both delimiter of CSV file and External table should be same
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE on my question:

I figured out that my table was a partitioned table that data cannot be loaded into it by just uploading a csv file into the table folder. Insert Overwrite table by static partition/dynamic partition should be used instead.